# React-Native Zendesk Auth integration

Tags: objective-c, react-native, zendesk

I am trying to integrate zendesk with react-native. The problem is that I don't know objective-c so I am having problem with the authentication.
I want to open ZenDeskChat, for that I can do it in 2 different way (anonymous or auth). To use the auth procedure I have to create a JWT from my server and send this token to zendesk before I open the chat. I copy some function from zendesk documentation but because my lake of knowladge with objective-c I can't figure out how to pass the token to zendesk.

I don't know how to use this code.

```
    @implementation ZDKAuthJWT
​
- (void)getToken:(void (^)(NSString * _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable))completion {
    // Call completion block once you get the JWT token
    completion(<"token">, <"error">);
}
```

I am supposed to call it somewhere here :

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setUserIdentity: (NSDictionary *)user) {
  if (user[@"token"]) {
    id<ZDKObjCIdentity> userIdentity = [[ZDKObjCJwt alloc] initWithToken:user[@"token"]];
    [[ZDKZendesk instance] setIdentity:userIdentity];
    
    RCTAuthJWT *authenticator = [RCTAuthJWT new];
    [ZDKChat.instance setIdentityWithAuthenticator:authenticator];
    
  } else {
    id<ZDKObjCIdentity> userIdentity = [[ZDKObjCAnonymous alloc] initWithName:user[@"name"] // name is nullable
                                          email:user[@"email"]]; // email is nullable
    [[ZDKZendesk instance] setIdentity:userIdentity];
  }
}
```

Comment: There are existing libraries that wrap the Zendesk SDKs for React Native, have you looked at those? They should give you ideas for how to complete your task.

Comment: yes I did. I actually copy the code and create my own wrapper but they don't have the JWT auth integration